# How to stop Google Drive from sorting folders above files?

Tags: google-drive

I'm stunned I can't even find a discussion on this in all my searching.

Google Drive allows for sorting the contents of your drive by "Title".  However for some reason it places all folders above files, which is completely maddening.

Is there any way to get Drive to actually sort things alphabetically as would normally be expected in any standard filesystem?

Comment: thats not possible. also standard windows does the same

Comment: Wow that's dreadful.  Wherever I run Windows, I guess I spend so little time in that environment that I never noticed it defaulting that way.  Somehow it's a lot more annoying in Google Drive.